# Copying a Linked List crashes the Program

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy, nodes

I have Linked List code, the `Copy_List` function crashes the program and won't work: it gives no syntax error so it's logical. I'm not sure where the exact problem lies, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node{
   int info;
   node *link;
};


class Linked_List{
   private :

   int count;
   node *first;
   node *last;
   node *current;

   public:


   Linked_List() {

      count=0;
      first=NULL;
      last=NULL;
   }

   void Initialize_List(){

      cout<<"Enter Number OF Nodes"<<endl;
      cin>>count;

      first=last=current=new node;

      for(int i =0;i<count;i++){
         cout<<"Enter New Node Info :"<<endl;
         cin>>current->info;
         last->link=current;
         last=current;
         current=new node;
      }

      last->link=NULL;
   }

   bool Is_Empty(){
      if(first==NULL)
      {
         return true;
      }
      else{
         return false;
      }
   }

   int Front () {
      if (first != NULL)

      return first-> info; 
      else return 0;
   }

   int Back () {

      if (last != NULL)
      return last-> info;
      else return 0; 
   }

   void Insert_Last(int x){

      count++;
      current=new node;
      current->info=x;

      last->link=current;

      last=current;
      last->link=NULL;

      if(first==NULL)

      first=current;
   }

   void Delete_First(){

      if(!Is_Empty())  // Or if(first==NULL)
      { 

         node *p;
         p=first;
         first=first->link;
         delete p;
         count --;
         if(count==0)
            first=last=NULL;
      }
   }

  friend void Copy_List (Linked_List &n,Linked_List &m);

};

void Copy_List (Linked_List &n,Linked_List &m){

   Linked_List temp;
   while(!n.Is_Empty()){
      temp.Insert_Last(n.Front());
      n.Delete_First(); 
   }
   while (!temp.Is_Empty()) {

      n.Insert_Last(temp.Front());
      temp.Delete_First(); 
   }
}


void main (){
   Linked_List obj,obj2;
   cout<<"Is the list empty ?"<<"  "<<boolalpha<<obj.Is_Empty(); cout<<endl;
   obj.Initialize_List();
   cout<<"Is the list empty ?"<<"  "<<boolalpha<<obj.Is_Empty(); cout<<endl;
   Copy_List (obj,obj2);   
}
```

Comment: Set some debug points in `Copy_List` and see where it crashes.. then tell us which line, and what the scenario is. Also, some print statements could be useful to you while you're debugging ..

Comment: What's the point of `Linked_List &m`? You're not using it.. but I assume you think you are.

Comment: @MrDuk Linked_List &m  is to refer to the other object i want the list to be copied to .

Comment: I sadly don't know how to debug , I'm still fresh new to c++ .

Comment: That's fine; but you're not doing that - or even attempting to. `m` is non-existent in your `Copy_List` method.

Comment: *Aside*: `main` must return `int`.

Comment: Being fresh to [tag:c++] (or any language) is a great time to learn to debug... it's as much a part of programming as learning language syntax and semantics, system design and testing. Please don't let inexperience be an excuse for not debugging by yourself.

Comment: @MrDuk i tried add m.Insert_Last(n.Front());   after  temp.Insert_Last(n.Front());  and then called n.Delete_First(); }

it still crashes ...

Comment: @Johnsyweb i got your point but I'm in not the best timing to learn how to debug now , i need to fix this code as fast as i can , I really appreciate your advice and respect your opinion , by the way idk why i shall use int main here ?

everything else works fine without this function .

Comment: @user3555235 remove the line `last->link=current;` like I wrote in the answer. Does it crash?

Comment: @MrDuk i tried putting print statements and the crash happens right after while ,  it crashes  in : temp.Insert_Last(n.Front());

Comment: What I don't understand is how you've made it to implementing a linked list in your coursework, and still don't know how to debug your code.. it's safe to assume that without showing some effort to debug this yourself, we're not going to help too much.

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko yes it did :(

Comment: @user3555235 So what - it crashes?

Comment: Add more print statements - descriptive print statements; in every loop even. Be sure you're assigning the values you think you are. Even if you don't know how to debug using an IDE, you can still go through your loops, starting in `main()` with a piece of paper and a pencil.

Comment: @MrDuk The reason is my professor never mentioned debugging or gave hints on how to debug , she give us the basics of a specific idea then asks for a code to be written by me and other students , i learned a lot using internet and working on C++ , but never tried debug or tried it

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko yes it did sadly , it done copying but when i called Print function print the copied object and it gave the full list but after the last node it gave a rubbish value node and then crashed

Comment: @MrDuk i did , it crashes right  on  temp.Insert_Last(n.Front());

Comment: @user3555235 Print crash is another question though! Copy_List now is not crashing, that's the answer.

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko how is that another problem ?? 

it gives another rubbish value after last node , that means there is error in the copying function or insert_last function !

Comment: @user3555235 Try to debug and fix it. I showed you the idea what kind of problems there can be. If you don't know how to debug, you are not ready for this task.

Comment: If you don't know how to debug, you are not ready for any task. You cannot develop software, you do not have the required skillset.

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko this task is required in my next test and me or other students learn nothing about debug ! 

thanks for trying to help but i need to make it work even if i don't know how to debug ...

Comment: @MartinJames as i asid before , I'M Fresh new to c++ , debugging and developing needs more than my skills with programming , if you guys judging people by their questions that's a pity ....

Comment: I cannot judge you by anything else.  I dont' know you and have not read any works by you.  If. You. Cannot. Debug. You. Cannot. Write. Programs.  It really is that simple.  Tell your prof/TA that asking you to 'write programs' without any debugging aids or skills is just a waste of everybody's time, including yours.

Comment: Also, the students who get high marks are unlikely be the ones who just deliver code copied from a fix provided by site like SO.  They will be the ones who learned how to write the programs and also, on their own initiative, learned how debug them to get them working.  The students who don't do that are also-rans.

Comment: @MartinJames  i will look at it and learn it for sure , but SO is really a great website that taught me a lot on android before and yes without understanding you can't program ! 

thanks for your time and advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions for improvement:

- Add a default constructor to `node` so that it gets initialized properly when constructed.

  ```
  struct node{
      node(int in = 0) : info(in), link(NULL) {}
     int info;
     node *link;
  };
  ```
- You don't need `current` as a member of `Linked_List`. It's useful only in some functions as a function varible.
- Implement `Initialize_List()` using `Insert_Last`. That keeps the function cleaner. It also avoids redundant code.

  ```
  void Initialize_List(){
    cout<<"Enter Number OF Nodes"<<endl;
    int num;
    cin>>num;

    for(int i =0;i<num;i++){
       cout<<"Enter New Node Info :"<<endl;
       int info;
       cin >> info;
       this->Insert_Last(info);
    }
  }
  ```
- `Insert_Last` had assumptions about which is a valid pointer and which is not, which won't be true if you started using to from `Initialize_List`. It can be simplified to:

  ```
  void Insert_Last(int x){
    count++;
    node* current=new node;
    current->info=x;

    if ( first == NULL )
    {
       first = last = current;
    }
    else
    {
       last->link=current;
       last=current;
    }
  }
  ```
- Implementation of `Copy_List` you posted deleted all items from the first argument and put them in the second argument. I am not sure that was the purpose. If you want to keep the contents of the first argument unchanged and want to copy its contents to the second argument, an alternate method is necessary. Here's what I came up with:

  ```
  void Copy_List (Linked_List &n,Linked_List &m){

     Linked_List temp;
     node* current = n.first;
     for ( ; current != NULL; current = current->link )
     {
        temp.Insert_Last(current->info);
     }

     current = temp.first;
     for ( ; current != NULL; current = current->link )
     {
        m.Insert_Last(current->info);
     }
  }
  ```
- You don't have a destructor in `Linked_List`. The default implementation provided by the compiler won't release the memory allocated by the class. In order to deallocate the memory allocated by the class, you need to implement a destructor.

  ```
  ~Linked_List() {
    node* current=first;
    while ( current != NULL )
    {
       node* temp = current->link;
       delete current;
       current = temp;
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much ! 

I just edited my Insert_Last and it worked ! :D

thank you for solving my 2 hours problem of misery !

Answer (score 1):

In the new list `last` pointer is not initialized firstly:

```
void Insert_Last(int x) {
   ...
   last->link=current;   // for the new List last should be initialized 
   last = current;
   last->link=NULL;
```

Supposed change - remove the line `last->link=current;`

```
   last = current;
   last->link=NULL;
```